# Will Drive download URLs stop working on 2 January 2024?

Tags: google-drive, cookies

[Google Workspace Updates](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/10/upcoming-changes-to-third-party-cookies-in-google-drive.html) made an announcement regarding third-party cookie requirements in Google Drive with the following notice:

> Starting January 2, 2024, Drive will start serving downloads without
> requiring third-party cookies that are embedded on third-party
> websites. This is separate from downloading files from Drive.
>
> If you have specific workflows in place that rely on Drive’s download
> URLs or use an app which relies on Drive’s download URLs, you’ll need
> to switch to the Drive and Docs publishing flows by January 2, 2024.

The notice states that *"If you... use an app which relies on Drive’s download URLs, you’ll need to switch to the Drive and Docs publishing flows..."*, but it is unclear how specifically this relates to Drive's third-party cookie support. This lack of clarity is the foundation of my question:

I maintain a web application that uses `iframe`s to embed content from Google Drive for presentation purposes, using download URLs (generated using the "Share" link) as follow e.g.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/ABC/embed" .../>
```

The content permissions are set to **`Anyone with the link:Viewer`** - as such the content is publicly accessible (read-only) without requiring being logged into a Google account.

The context of the notice is around Drive's use of third-party cookies, however I am unsure of how Drive works under the hood w.r.t. sharing content and whether this notice in some way applies implicitly to my use-case. More specifically, it is unclear to me which "specific workflows" the Google notice refers to and whether my use-case will be one of the workflows impacted by this change.

Does anyone know which specific workflows the notice refers to, and whether my use-case is considered one of these workflows?

---

I posted a version of this same question on the [Google Help Community Forum](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/243869137) with no responses so far.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149969/discussion-on-question-by-riaandp-will-drive-download-urls-stop-working-on-2-jan); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.